# Do OpenCV operations impede NumPy arithmetic?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm attempting to use NumPy and OpenCV to perform object anonymization. The objective is to anonymize faces by isolating them with a mask, blurring said content, and then joining the result to another image. The other image is gotten by inverting the mask and applying it to the source image. The two pieces are combined by addition.

```
def apply_mask(image, mask):
    return np.multiply(image, mask)
```

Let's test this on a toy example:

```
image = np.random.randn(256,256)
mask = Mask(256, 256, [64, 64, 192, 192])
```

Here we've created an object such that mask.inverted_array_label is a 256x256 monochrome image with all pixel intensities zero, except for the rectangle with upper left corner (64,64) and lower right corner (192,192). All pixels in this rectangle have intensity 1.

```
kernel_size = (121,121)
X = apply_mask(image, mask.inverted_array_label)
X = cv2.GaussianBlur(X, kernel_size, 0)
plt.imshow(X, cmap="gray")
```

[image: So far, so good . . .]

Now we apply a Gaussian blur to the inverted mask, then apply the result to the original image . . .

```
opp_mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask.array_label, kernel_size, 0)
Y = apply_mask(image, opp_mask)
plt.imshow(Y, cmap="gray")
```

[image]

Now I want to add the first image to the second.

```
Z = np.zeros(X.shape)
Z = np.add(X,Y)
plt.imshow(Z, cmap="gray")
num = 190
print(X[num,num], Y[num,num], Z[num,num])
w1 = X[num, num]
w2 = Y[num, num]
w3 = w1+w2
print(w1,w2,w3)
```

The arithmetic checks out:

```
0.006876066498679399 0.7493522694977256 0.756228335996405
0.006876066498679399 0.7493522694977256 0.756228335996405
```

However, the image does not change as expected:

[image]

What am I missing? How do I properly add these two arrays?

Comment: `128` and `218` are different numbers. What happens if you fix that?

Comment: You're right. Edit is coming shortly . . .

Comment: It looks to me like your second array has a much bigger value range, which isn't visible when both arrays get autoscaled to the same range by `imshow`, but is much more visible when you add the values together and the second array completely swamps the first. What do you get if you `print(X.min(), X.max(), Y.min(), Y.max())`?

Comment: Again, it looks like you're correct . . . Y's values have a much broader range: X.min: -0.025475747083989565 X.max: 0.02673418711816738  Y.min: -4.556534671912842 Y.max: 4.156018274709479

Comment: With that information about minimun and maximun put both images in the same range: `X = (X-Xmin)/(Xmax-Xmin)` and `Y = (Y-Ymin)/(Ymax-Ymin)` and then try to apply the mask again